# Discord.py бот выдает что я угадал,даже если я не угадал

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Я новичок в discord.py да и в целом в Python.

Написал я команду,все выполняется,но когда я угадываю число,бот все равно пишет что я не угадал. Почему так?
Вот мой код:

```
@client.command()
async def roll(ctx, a1number):
    botnumber = random.randint(0, 6)
    if a1number == botnumber:
        await ctx.send('You guessed! The number is: ' + str(botnumber)  +  '')
    else:
        await ctx.send('You didnt guessed :( The number is: ' + str(botnumber)  +  '')
```

это выдает что я не угадал даже при том что я угадал

Comment: У вас в заголовке вопроса написано противоположное тому, что написано в теле вопроса. Приведите в соответствие.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> это выдает что я не угадал даже при том что я угадал

Вы отправляете боту строку, а не целочисленное число.
А `random.randint(0, 6)` возвращает целочисленное число. Вам нужно сравнить либо `str` с `str`, либо `int` с `int`.
Попробуйте сделать так:

```
if a1number == str(botnumber) :
```

или

```
if int(a1number) == botnumber:
```

---

Или можно сразу принимать аргумент `a1number` в виде числа:

```
async def roll(ctx, a1number: int):
```